# Filter datatable to list only selected rows

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Is there a way to filter the `datatable` to the selected rows?

I have a huge data frame with 20000 rows and it is a bit tricky if you search and select some rows. If you want to unselect them, you have to go through the list and search the already clicked lines or reset your complete selection.

I think it would be nice to filter the table to only selected rows and the user can unselect those again.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
        DT::dataTableOutput("name_table")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$name_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(mtcars,
                  options=list(pageLength=5),
                  selection=list(selected=c(1,3,32)))
  })
  name_proxy = DT::dataTableProxy('name_table')
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So in my example it should filter the list to row 1,3 and 32 and all three should be selected so I can unselect them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible with just one table, but by creating a second table that contains all the selected entries and by allowing the selections in the first table to be updated based on what you (un)select in the second table, you get the desired effect. 
Because the reactivity of the tables was causing issues, I added an `actionButton` around the updating of the selection, but I think it should be doable without it.

Currently the second table always shows whatever is selected in the first table with all rows selected. If you want to trim the selection you unselect a row in the second table and press the `Update selections` button

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("name_table"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("selected_table"),
    actionButton("selectbutton", label = "Update selections")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mtcarsmod <- mtcars # We need a table with the row numbers as a column
  mtcarsmod$Rownr <- 1:nrow(mtcars)

  output$name_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(mtcarsmod,
                  options=list(pageLength=5),
                  # Have those rows selected that show up in the selected_table
                  selection= list(selected=
                                    c(1,3,32)
                  )
    )
  })

  name_proxy <- DT::dataTableProxy('name_table') # Proxy to use for updating the selection

  mtcars_selected <- reactive(mtcarsmod[input$name_table_rows_selected,]) # The selected options from the first table

  output$selected_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    try(DT::datatable(mtcars_selected(),
                      options=list(pageLength=5),
                      # have all entries selected
                      selection= list(selected=
                                        1:nrow(mtcars_selected()))
    ))
  })


  observeEvent(input$selectbutton,  # When you press the button update the selections in the first table
               selectRows(name_proxy, mtcars_selected()[input$selected_table_rows_selected,"Rownr"])
  )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I was more looking for a solution to update the displayed data in the way to show only the selected rows... The two table version works and I used before but is not handy at all...

Comment: That's just a matter of displaying the tables differently. For example if you have a tab with the main table and a tab with the selected table, switching tabs basically "updates the displayed data to show only the selected rows" right? Maybe I'm not understanding a part of what you're trying to achieve.